# Bluetooth cross platform android, iphone, Blackberry, Symbian, WinMo

Tags: iphone, android, ios, cross-platform, bluetooth

i've been doing research as the title said. FYI im not familiar with iphone and android code. I've only done in j2me before. That's why i want to learn it but in more practical ways because i need to do this in 1 or 2 months.
I want to make an application that send data between two connected devices. both device can be the same OS but can be different.

I search for framework that can be converted to specific OS: phonegap, titanium, corona (but corona only for android and iphone).

However, below is my problem:

1. I found that iOS bluetooth cannot connect and send data to android or other devices. 
   http://www.quora.com/What-is-an-example-of-a-bluetooth-app-across-both-iPhone-and-Android

any way to do it? jailbreaking is okay because im not gonna publish it. I've read that with jailbreaking is possible to make the bluetooth more open but i cannot find whether with jailbreaking the iphone can connect bluetooth and send data to other devices.

1. For phonegap framework, is it still not support bluetooth?
   http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/325911ec73e64aba/8d1aa39a3d03cedd?lnk=gst&q=bluetooth#8d1aa39a3d03cedd

Any ideas what framework should i use? because i will not try one by one because there is not enough time. And is it possible to have an application that connect cross platform with bluetooth as the title said?

Comment: erdic: Are you able to complete this,if you are successful, could you please post your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a cross platform app, with BT capabilities (between many others) using motorola's Rhomobile Suite http://www.rhomobile.com/, using the Ruby language.
I am developing something using it, it seems rather easy to use. The thing for us is that to use Classic BT you can't develop for iPhone (without jail braking), and using BT LE is still limited to few devices.

Answer (score 0):

Another question on SO may provide you more information:
[Bluetooth LE app, how to build it cross-plaftorm (iOS-Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812689/bluetooth-le-app-how-to-build-it-cross-plaftorm-ios-android/32214119#32214119)

It doesn't answer your first question but contains information regarding Bluetooth on PhoneGap. I personally am using Qt for Bluetooth enabled app development if that may interest you.