# Bluetooth LE app, how to build it cross-plaftorm (iOS-Android)?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an app that talks to a Bluetooth LE device.  I would like some way to avoid developing it *twice*, for iOS and for Android.  Is there a cross-platform app framework that has good support for Bluetooth LE?

I have had a quick look at frameworks like Cordova (PhoneGap), Appcelerator, Xamarin etc (the usual suspects: for example [this list](http://appindex.com/blog/ten-best-cross-platform-development-mobile-enterprises/)) but I can't figure out if they (a) support Bluetooth LE on each platform at all, and (b) if they do, whether it is via native calls (accessed how?) or some kind of wrapper to the native API (what does the wrapper look like?), and (c) if it is a wrapper, how complete it is, and how stable it is.

If you have experience with these, could you summarize the status of Bluetooth LE support in different frameworks?

**EDIT** A bit of info from digging into various options and from the answers below:

- Cordova: several open-source plugins, for example https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE (not a complete list). Evothings is a nice Cordova + bluetooth setup.  Do these work in other Cordova-based app frameworks like Appery.io, Telerik AppBuilder, Ionic Creator?
- Xamarin: this just uses the native APIs via [MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3AMonoTouch.CoreBluetooth) and [Android.Bluetooth](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3AAndroid.Bluetooth).  This means the code using them is not actually cross-platform, but they are likely to work the same as the native API (because they essentially are the native API).
- Appcelerator has third-party commercial plugins for Bluetooth (https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3834 and 
  https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/6611), no built-in support.  Do these work?

P.S. Besides Bluetooth my needs are pretty minimal: this app will have a lot of UI elements but not of a complicated kind, just a bunch of buttons/checkboxes/sliders on a bunch of different screens (which would be very tedious to maintain on two platforms).  I'd also need to make a few calls to a REST API.  Speed is not super important, there isn't that much app logic (it is mostly written in C now), and native UI look is not that important.  However working on older versions of the platforms *is* important, ideally back to Android 4.3 and iOS 7.0.

Comment: There are several plugins with Phonegap about blueooth low energy. And if you need UI elements, I think you will get all of them easily using HTML5/CSS. But building for the both environment isn't that easy that it looks like as you need two proper environment for each OS. Take a look at the documentation and how Phonegap works.http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview . Last if you want to sell your app one day, note that Xamarin and Appcelerator have license fees and Cordova is free.

Comment: To everyone who is voting to close this, can you please explain why?  This is squarely on topic (see: "software tools commonly used by programmers" etc).  It is not asking for *recommendations based on opinion*, but rather asking about facts ("does this work in framework X?").  Thus, I am perplexed about what the problem is.

Comment: can you share what you ended up with (if you did) ? Thanks

Comment: @AlexI Which solution did you end up using?  I am currently evaluating Cordova/Ionic with BLECentralPlugin.  I am finding that working with such a framework is not intuitive to someone coming from a traditional Android Development background...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky  I first developed a simple iOS native app, then switched to Cordova with randduisng/BluetoothLE plugin.  Works well, haven't seen any plugin-related issues. Cordova 6.1 for iOS 10.x, Android 6.x.

Comment: @AlexI  Do you find performance and look/feel of the Cordova app comparable to the iOS native app you built?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using [Randdusing](https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE)'s Cordova plugin for BluetoothLE and it works well for Android and iOS (Windows phone still under development). Being Cordova it's designed to work with an HTML5/JavaScript app, but the plugins themselves (as all Cordova plugins?) are written in native code .
Earlier in my project I tried [Evothings](http://evothings.com/) which also has  BLE plugin but I found some problems, and I don't know if these have been resolved yet.
My app sounds pretty similar to yours in terms of the UI requirements, and I can possibly help with integrating the BLE code if you like - but you'll need to rewrite your 'c' into javascript first.
BTW you ask for using with older Android but AFAIK BLE is only supported in [Android 4.3 or higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

Comment: I'll definitely check out the Cordova plugin. What did you run into with Evothings? (it looks really neat but I haven't tried it yet).

Comment: Are you able to connect phone-to-phone with the bluetoothle plugin? Just to send data from say an android phone to a windows phone over Bluetooth.

Comment: Did you ever find an iOS sample cordova app for Randdusing's? The one I found from M$ seems to only support Android/Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Qt framework developing cross-platform apps with BLE support:
  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-lowenergyscanner-example.html

Currently the supported platforms are Andriod, iOS, OSX, Linux. Windows platform is said to support BLE in the forthcoming version Qt 5.6 (really looking forward to it). The BLE related classes are easy to use and Qt provided two sample projects in examples/documentation. The thing I am not sure about is getting Manufacturer Specific Data during a scan. Right now I am making a connection to the devices to get certain information which wouldn't be needed if I can read the Manufacturer Specific Data. Qt's BLE currently only support central role.

Qt is based on C++, if that matters to you.

Comment: Have you published this app?  I am really curious to try it and evaluate its performance and aesthetics...